# Python - unpack list of lists

Tags: python

What is the cleanest way to implement the following:

```
list = [list1, list2, ...]
return [*list1, *list2, ...]
```

It looks like this syntax will be available in Python 3.5. In the meantime, what is your solution?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is commonly written as:

```
[x for l in list for x in l]
```

Comment: I have never seen this before, so +1, but I'm not really sure what's going on...

Comment: Check out list comprehensions in python.